# Is there a way to collaborate on vscode and have both people see html site

Tags: visual-studio-code

On VScode is there a way to collaborate with multiple people and have them both be able to see the live preview. I know that the live preview is a file on the local computer but I was wondering if there is a way to host them on a server. When I tried before, only 1 person gets the live preview option.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Live Share](https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share) extension: https://code.visualstudio.com/learn/collaboration/live-share

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that can be done by screen sharing, there are so many screen sharing software out there like Zoom, Skype etc

Another method will be to own a website or other free web hosting sites like Heroku etc.